# bash file cannot be executed dynamically because of command not found

Tags: bash

i'm having trouble fixing the error in this bash script, I seriously have no idea what I did wrong, any help is appreciated thanks. 
I already add a space between the [ and -f, but the error
-bash: [-f: command not found
still exits.

```
-bash: [-f: command not found
```

This is the bash file.

```
#! /bin/bash
if [ -f  /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

umask 022
HOSTNAME=`uname -n`
export PS1="[\u@\h \w]\\$ "

export CLICOLOR=1
export TERM=xterm
export SVN_EDITOR=vim
export CSCOPE_EDITOR=vim

export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
export GREP_COLOR='1;37;41'
```

EDIT: I deleted the space at the first line, #!/bin/bash, and also checked /etc/bashrc. The problem

```
-bash: [-f command not found
```

still exits. I have no idea about this. Thank you for your answers.

Ans: I found that the error was caused by bash_profile rather than bashrc. Thank you all for answering.

Comment: All signs point towards the fact that the file you have included is not the one that you're running.The `>` before `fi` looks like it may have been copied from a terminal at some point. Furthermore, your first line should be `#!/bin/bash` (no space)

Comment: The space in the shebang line doesn't matter but the rest of that is true. Also, and this is specifically relevant here, the `if` line is the one that had the problem in the original but that has been corrected for this paste. The space between `[` and `-f` is **necessary**.

Comment: "I already add a space between the [ and -f, but the error -bash: [-f: command not found still exits." Sounds impossible to me.

Comment: Has `/etc/bashrc` been modified to contain something like `if [-f ....`? Or is that possibly not actually a space there, but a different character or sequence of characters that just displays as a space?

Comment: Run `bash -x your_script_here` to see exactly which line is causing the issue.  Then include that line.